# String.fromCharCode(61444) from FontAwesome

Tags: html, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome.ttf and `<p>String.fromCharCode(61444)</p>` or `<Text>String.fromCharCode</Text>` prints **heart icon**.

Where does `61444` come from??? How can I encode or decode it? (heart icon is `&#xf004;`)

Thanks!

p.s If you want to understand better, you may check the exact code here: https://github.com/akveo/kittenTricks/blob/master/app/assets/icons.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML character references (like `&#xf004;`) encode a Unicode character as a hexidecimal number. `61444` is the integer equivalent of `xf004` in hexidecimal, and thus is an equivalent value.

Comment: Perfect..!!!!!!!! I can't accept your answer yet since the system doesn't allow it yet. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

61444 is F004 in hexadecimal, which is the character code for the heart symbol. If you go to http://fontawesome.io/icon/heart/ you will find the unicode value of the fontawesome heart icon is f004.
.